# Can I change the firmware on a Retail EV3 Intelligent brick to the Educational version?

Tags: ev3, education

The LEGO Mindstorms EV3 comes in both educational and retail versions. The educational version differs in bricks, sensors, a rechargable battery and datalogging capability.

I would like to know can I change the firmware on the EV Intelligent brick to supporting datalogging?

And does this mean I need to buy and install educational version of software on my PC?

Comment: The hardware is most certainly identical, so I don't see why you wouldn't be able to change the firmware at will. Actually, I wonder if it isn't the exact same firmware to start with.

Answer (score 5):

There are indeed two versions of the firmware to support the two sets of capabilities of the EV3 Brick, both currently at version 1.3/1.03:

- EV3 Firmware V1.03**H**.bin - The current "Home" edition.
- EV3 Firmware V1.03**E**.bin - The current "Education" edition.

From what I've seen, you should be able to use either firmware on the bricks, however to get access to the data logging features you would also need to use the [Education version of the software as well](http://shop.legoeducation.com/gb/product/lego-mindstorms-education-ev3-software-single-user-2000045-200/):

> LEGO MINDSTORMS Education EV3 Software includes:
>
> - Data logging capabilities so students can log and analyse real-time sensor values.

Answer (score 2):

I'm now using Retail EV3 with Education firmware, and this magically solved all the problems with the Bluetooth connection. Apart from that, I couldn't find any other difference. So for me it works fine :)

Comment: I am still on Retail/Retail, and have not had a problem with Bluetooth